# Bing doesn't index my website correcty

Tags: seo, search-engines, bing

I have a website with robots and sitemap which is working on Google.
I created a bing webmasters and sent the sitemap some weeks ago, but whenever I search site:www.mysite.com I get only the root folder in my website.

I think this should be because I have no website in my root (www.mywebsite.com), if a user enters this domain, he is redirected to www.mywebsite.com/questions. Is there any way I can inform bing that this redirect is correct and should be followed?

thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bing will follow the redirect no problem so there's nothing you should alter if its a 301 redirect. Your find with Bing it takes many weeks and months to get into their indexed compared to Google. Also bing is much more fussy on indexing pages so ensure the page is uniqne and offers good content.

**Watching Bing Indexing is Like Watching Paint Dry**

I have over 20 sites and its very normal to find pages that are months old not indexed by Bing, sadly they are not as quickly to add pages as Google is. Since Google finds the page fine as long as your confident with your robots.txt looks good then there's nothing to worry about and its normal for Bing to take ages. Just be patient and build more quality content while you wait.